# how to use event bubbling cancellation

Tags: javascript, events, event-bubbling

I've looked everywhere for a code on how to stop event bubbling to occur, and I've found one from the Quirksmode website, which is this:

```
function doSomething(e){
    if(!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if(e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

But I don't know how and where to use it.
What is the 'e' parameter used as (or what should be passed as 'e')?
Is this function to be called in an event handler code?
...etc?

I need some help, please can someone give me some hint?

Basically I have 4 elements that have an 'onchange' handler called 'updateAvailableAttributes()', like this:

```
<select id="deliveryMethod" name="deliveryMethod" onchange="updateAvailableAttributes();"></select>

<select id="formatMethod" name="formatMethod" onchange="updateAvailableAttributes();"></select>

<select id="yearsMethod" name="yearsMethod" onchange="updateAvailableAttributes();"></select>

<select id="updateMethod" name="updateMethod" onchange="updateAvailableAttributes();"></select>
```

Here is the updateAvailableAttributes() script:

```
function updateAvailableAttributes() {
var form = document.forms["orderDefinition"];
form.elements["formChangeRequest"].value = "true";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax/possibleValues.html",
  data: $("form#orderDefinition").serialize(),
  success: function(response){
    $('#usercontent .sleeve .toprow').html(response);

    applyValidation();
    radioButtonHighlightSelection();

  },
  error: function(response, ioArgs) {
         if (response.status == 601) {
             sessionTimedOut();
         } 
      }
});

// Display a "please wait" message
$("#waitingMsgOverlay, #waitingMsgBox, #waitingMsg, #waitingMsgParag").ajaxStart(function(){
      var map = document.getElementById("OrderMap");
      map.disableApplication();
      $(this).show();
      radioButtonHighlightSelection();
  }).ajaxStop(function(){
      var map = document.getElementById("OrderMap");
      map.enableApplication();
      $(this).hide();
      $("#toolpanel").height($("#orderMap").height());
      radioButtonHighlightSelection();
});}
```

My question is, how do I incorporate the 'doSomething(e)' with 'updateAvailableAttributes()' I have already on the 'onchange' event handler?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e is the event. For example if u have a div inside another div and both of them have a js click handler called doSomething. so in the onclick attribute use onclick="doSomething(event);" if you click on the inner div outer will not handle it now

Comment: @Vinay B R: thanks for your response. I have edited my question for it to be clearer.

Comment: I'm still new to javascript so the event bubbling issue is still a bit confusing to me. I just wanna incorporate that doSomthing() with the function I have already in my 'onchange' handler. But how do I do that?

Comment: if you can paste your existing script here i can edit it for you

Comment: use onchange="updateAvailableAttributes();doSomething(event);"

Comment: Cool!! Thanks for this. Can I also call doSomething() inside of updateAvailableAttributes() and use 'this' to pass e as parameter? Maybe I'm thinking too much here...

Comment: in that case call updateAvailableAttributes(event) and pass event to doSomething

Answer (score 2):

The whole doSomething is the event handler itself. You just register the event exactly as you would if there was no parameter. The "e" parameter is provided by the JavaScript runtime itself.

Comment: @commanderz: Thanks for the answer. I have posted more information. To make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In DOM model there are various events associated with an element e.g. `onclick`. If you want to handle any event you attach an event listener to an element. e.g. `element.addEventListner(event,yourfunction,bubble)`.

see this http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: thanks you for the answer. I've just read the addEventListener article but because I'm kinda new to Javascript, I'm still missing the plot...