# Clickable image inside a clickable div calls both onclick handlers

Tags: javascript, html

here is my issue:

I have an **img** with an onclick handler inside a **div** that also has an onclick handler.

```
<div onclick="someFunction();">
  <img src="/Images/SomeImage.png" onclick="someOtherFunction();" />
</div>
```

When clicking on the image, I don't want the div's handler to be fired.

I have tried adding "return false;" at the end of my img's onclick, to no avail.

[image]

The reason I need it done that way is because I have a bunch of projects, hovering the div highlights that entry and if you click on it that'll show you more details, but you might also want to edit/delete that entry.

Thanks !!

Comment: Post your JavaScript code.

Comment: Here is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668324/how-to-use-event-bubbling-cancellation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `stopImmediatePropagation()` method to stop the immidiate propagation.

**HTML**

```
  <img src="/Images/SomeImage.png" onclick="someOtherFunction(event);" />
```

**javaScript**

```
 //this function stops the propagation and not triggered parent div's handler
function someOtherFunction(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/79QwW/1/)